# puppeteer: How to call action await page.goto(`${url}`); within .map((index, element) => {

Tags: puppeteer

I am scraping data from a webpage, pagination also works. 
I have a table with tr. 
For each tr, there is position, title, URL.

In function .map((index, element) => { i want to call for each tr "async url => { await page.goto(`${url}`);" and go to details scrape data from details page and return to lists.

how can i do it? (call async within .map())

```
      const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
      const cheerio = require("cheerio");


      async function scrapeListings(page) {
     await page.goto(
       "https://www.example.com/podcast-detail/nth28-2ef41/99%25-Invisible- 
      Podcast",
        { waitUntil: ["load", "domcontentloaded", "networkidle0"] }
    );

     let moreResults = true;

     while (moreResults) {
     console.log(moreResults);
      try {
      const html = await page.content();
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      const listings = $("#yw0 > table > tbody > tr")
        .map((index, element) => {
          const position = $(element)
            .find("td.id.tc")
            .text();
          const title = $(element)
            .find("a.title.listen-now")
            .text();
          const url = $(element)
            .find("a")
            .attr("href");
          const datetime = $(element)
            .find("span.datetime")
            .text();
          async url => {
            await page.goto(`${url}`);
            //Open URL for details
            //SCRAPE Details
            //return value and store to listing
          };
          return { position, title, datetime, url };
        })
        .get();

      await sleep(1000);
      element = await page.$x(`//a[contains(text(),'→')]`);
      await element[0].click();
      console.log(listings);
      //await page.waitForNavigation();
    } catch (error) {
      moreResults = false;
      }
      }
     }

     async function sleep(miliseconds) {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, miliseconds));
      }

    async function main() {
     //await connectToMongoDb();

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

     await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1057 });

     listings = await scrapeListings(page);

    console.log(listings);
     //await browser.close();
   }

    main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to recode your script to use only Puppeteer. No cheerio needed.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")

const pageURL = 'https://www.podbean.com/podcast-detail/nth28-2ef41/99%25-Invisible//page/25'
const uaString = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36'

let podCastsAll = []

;(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({
        headless: false,
        devtools: false
    })

    const [page] = await browser.pages ()

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout (0)
    page.setUserAgent ( uaString )
    page.setViewport ({ width: 1366, height: 768 })
    page.setRequestInterception ( true )

    page.on ( 'request', async request => {
        if ( request.resourceType () === 'image' || request.resourceType () === 'font' ) {
            request.abort ()
        } else {
            request.continue ()
        }
    })

    const getPodcast = async url => {
        const pagePod = await browser.newPage ()
        const openPod = await pagePod.goto ( url, { waitUntil: `networkidle0`, timeout: 0 })
        const waitPod = await pagePod.waitForSelector ('p.pod-name')

        const podName = await pagePod.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('p.pod-name').innerText )
        const podTime = await pagePod.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('.time > span').innerText )
        const podDesc = await pagePod.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('#desc').innerText )
        const podLink = await pagePod.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('.player iframe').src )

        const openLink = await pagePod.goto ( podLink, { waitUntil: `networkidle0`, timeout: 0 })
        const waitElem = await pagePod.waitForSelector ( 'audio[preload] > source[src]', { timeout: 0 })

        const podFile = await pagePod.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('audio[preload] > source[src]').src )

        const closeIt = await pagePod.close ()

        return ({
            name : podName,
            time : podTime,
            desc : podDesc,
            link : podLink,
            file : podFile
        })
    }

    const start = await page.goto ( pageURL, { waitUntil: `networkidle2`, timeout: 0 })

    const getThisPage = async () => {
        const wait = await page.waitForSelector ('.pagination > ul', { timeout: 0 })
        const items = await page.waitForSelector ('#yw0 > table > tbody > tr')

        const [podcasts, podNumber, podTitle, podDate, podURL] = await page.evaluate ( () => {
            let podcasts = document.querySelectorAll('#yw0 > table > tbody > tr')

            let podNumber = []
            let podTitle = []
            let podDate = []
            let podURL = []

            podcasts.forEach( elem => {
                podNumber.push( elem.querySelector('td.id.tc').innerText )
                podTitle.push( elem.querySelector('a.title.listen-now').innerText )
                podDate.push( elem.querySelector('span.datetime').innerText )
                podURL.push( elem.querySelector('a[href]').href )
            })

            return [podcasts, podNumber, podTitle, podDate, podURL]
        })

        let podcastsArray = []
        let podcastDetail = []

        for ( let num in podcasts ) {
            podcastDetail = []

            podcastsArray[num] = {
                number: podNumber[num],
                title: podTitle[num],
                datetime: podDate[num],
                link: podURL[num]
            }

            podcastDetail[num] = await getPodcast ( podURL[num] )

            podcastsArray[num].desc = podcastDetail[num].desc
            podcastsArray[num].play = podcastDetail[num].link
            podcastsArray[num].source = podcastDetail[num].file

            await page.waitFor (1000)
        }

        podCastsAll = podCastsAll.concat( podcastsArray )

        var nextEnabled = await page.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector( '.pagination > ul > li.next.disabled' ) === null )
        console.log ('NEXT PAGE >>>')
        if (nextEnabled) {
            var thisPage = await page.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector( '.pagination > ul > li.active > a[href]' ).innerText )
            const next = await page.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector( '.pagination > ul > li.next > a' ).click() )

            while ( thisPage === await page.evaluate ( () =>  document.querySelector( '.pagination > ul > li.active > a[href]' ).innerText ) ) {
                await page.waitFor (100)
            }

            await getThisPage ()
        } else {
            console.log ('FINISHED!\n')
            console.log (podCastsAll)
        }
    }

    await getThisPage()

})()
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. It works really fine.

Answer (score 0):

if somebody need to click on link and open a new page instead to call url this is code: 
maybe some has a better solution, be free to share thanks a lot

```
const getPodcast = async url => {
    const pageTarget = page.target();
    await page.click(".table > .items > tr > td > .title");
    const newTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(
    target => target.opener() === pageTarget
    );
    const pagePod = await newTarget.page();
    console.log("current page count ", (await browser.pages()).length);
    //const pagePod = await browser.newPage();
    //const openPod = await pagePod.goto(url, {  waitUntil: `networkidle0`,   
    timeout: 0 });
```